# Can I use adsutil.vbs to remove the 'X—Powered-By' response header from IIS6

Tags: iis, iis-6, deployment, automation, http-headers

Can I use `adsutil.vbs` to remove the `X—Powered-By` response header from IIS6 configuration?

We have a site that is running on some IIS6 servers. Migration to IIS7 is a few months away at least. In the mean time, I have noticed that it is serving the header `X—Powered-By: ASP.NET` on all responses. I want this gone since it is a waste of bytes and a minor security risk. I strongly prefer to script this so that future deployments also ensure that the header is not present.

We have one or two custom headers that I want to keep, but those should be added by the deployment script so clearing them all upfront may be an option.

Is there a way to do this using `adsutil.vbs`?

Answer (score 2):

To get the current custom headers:

`cscript adsutil.vbs GET W3SVC\HttpCustomHeaders`

and to clear them all:

`cscript adsutil.vbs SET W3SVC\HttpCustomHeaders ""`

You can obviously do this at a site level by inserting the site ID: `W3SVC\123\HttpCustomHeaders`

Comment: I definitely don't want to clear them all - just the "X—Powered-By" one. The automation would also have to determine the right site id.

Comment: Do you use any other custom ones? If so you can just use the `SET` command, re-adding in all the custom headers but exclude the Powered-by one. As for the site ID, as long as the sites are all named the same way (and were named that way when they were created), the IDs should be the same. IIS6 generated the ID based on the site name when creating the site. Check first though!

Comment: I have expanded on this in the question. it may be an option. Thanks.